# How do I deliver the video to the neural network

Tags: python, pytorch

I wanted to test the effect of video compression using models from the compressai library. Here is the compressai library.https://github.com/InterDigitalInc/CompressAI.
But I don't know why it's reporting an error, please help me to feed the test video to the network and get the compressed video result

```
# pip install compressai
# pip install av

import math
import cv2
import io
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
import numpy as np
from pytorch_msssim import ms_ssim
from PIL import Image
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from compressai.zoo import ssf2020
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
# Pre-trained model
net = ssf2020(quality=4, pretrained=True).eval()
print(net)


import os
import av

def get_tensor_from_video(video_path, is_multi_thread_decode=True):
    """
    video_path: 
    is_multi_thread_decode: 
    return: pytorch tensor
    """
    if not os.access(video_path, os.F_OK):
        print('The test file does not exist')
        return
    container = av.open(video_path)
    if is_multi_thread_decode:
        container.streams.video[0].thread_type = "AUTO"
    container.seek(0, any_frame=False, backward=True, stream=container.streams.video[0])
    frames = []
    for frame in container.decode(video=0):
        frames.append(frame)
    container.close()

    result_frames = None

    result_frames = [frame.to_rgb().to_ndarray() for frame in frames]

    result_frames = torch.Tensor(np.stack(result_frames))

    # the result_frames consist of the dimensions [number of video frames, width, height, number of channels]
    return result_frames
cap = get_tensor_from_video('/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks3/test.avi') 
cap = cap.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)  # Swap the dimensions in it to make the cap into N,C,H,W format
print(len(cap))    
print(cap.size())  

#I guessed that its input would be a list, and each item in the list would be in tensor format, so I wrote the following
lists = []

for i in range(len(cap)):
    lists.append(cap[i])

with torch.no_grad():
    x_hat, likelihoods = net.forward(lists)
```

```
Output:
795
torch.Size([795, 3, 576, 768])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1e526b5fdfa4> in <module>
     41 
     42 with torch.no_grad():
---> 43   x_hat,likelihoods = net.forward(lists)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/compressai/entropy_models/entropy_models.py in quantize(self, inputs, mode, means)
    167         outputs = inputs.clone()
    168         if means is not None:
--> 169             outputs -= means
    170 
    171         outputs = torch.round(outputs)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (5) must match the size of tensor b (192) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

Comment: You should extend "an error" to a real error description including the full error traceback if available.

Comment: OK, I've put the error message above.